# MathJax Equation Wrap

Tags: mathjax

Hey,
Does anyone knows a good way to have MathJax automatically wrap equations if the containing element is with fixed size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MathJax v2.0 now includes automatic (optional) line breaking for long displayed equations.  It is controlled by the `linebreaks` section of the `HTML-CSS` block of your configuration.  See the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html?highlight=automatic%20line%20breaking#automatic-line-breaking) for details.